# Making a square root for python calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, square-root

I am new to Python and writing an engineering calculator on it. But i can't make a square root function currently. For example - this one show me an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str' ". Do you have any ideas how to make it work properly?

```
    def square_root(self, number=1):
        e.delete(0, END)
        self.value = float(self.value ** (1/number))
        e.insert(0, self.value)

button_root = Button(gui, text="√", padx=40, pady=40, command=lambda: calculus.square_root(""))

button_root.grid(row=2, column=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error says: you're passing a `str` (`""`) as your `number` for `calculus.square_root`. Change this to an `int` or `float` so that `1/number` can be evaluated. Also, you might want to check for cases when `number` equals 0, as dividing by zero will lead to a `ZeroDivisionError`.